# How can I make my filtering and mapping of arrays more compact and less repetitive?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So I have an array of objects, which I map and display based on which filtering option is set.

This is the example array :

`[ { "id": 1, "class": "Assault Infantry", "missions": 5, "shots": 28, "hits": 21, "kills": 22, "dead": true, }, { "id": 2, "class": "Field Medic", "missions": 5, "shots": 22, "hits": 17, "kills": 15, "dead": false, }, { "id": 3, "class": "Field Medic", "missions": 3, "shots": 15, "hits": 11, "kills": 8, "dead": true, }, { "id": 4, "class": "Skirmisher", "missions": 7, "shots": 38, "hits": 27, "kills": 25, "dead": false, }, { "id": 5, "class": "Phalanx", "missions": 2, "shots": 5, "hits": 3, "kills": 5, "dead": true, }, { "id": 6, "missions": 6, "shots": 50, "hits": 41, "kills": 31, "dead": false, }, { "id": 7, "class": "Rookie", "missions": 1, "shots": 2, "hits": 1, "kills": 1, "dead": true, },`

Then I have selectors that select particular fields, and sort the arrays by the chosen value by using state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('kills');
```

```
<select onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="kills">Kills</option>
          <option value="shots">Shots</option>
          <option value="missions">Missions</option>
          <option value="accuracy">Accuracy</option>
        </select>
```

Following there's a checkbox that if checked filters the sorted array further and removes specific instances:

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

const handleOnChange = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  };

<input onChange={handleOnChange} type="checkbox" id="isDead" name="isDead" checked={isChecked} />
 <label htmlFor="isDead">Hide Dead</label>
```

This is the code that does most of the sorting and filtering, and currently it works as expected and I'm happy how it works:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const sortArray = type => {
      const types = {
        mvps: 'mvps',
        kills: 'kills',
        shots: 'shots',
        missions: 'missions',
      };

      const sortProperty = types[type];
  
      if(sortType === "accuracy") {
        if(isChecked) {
          console.log(isChecked);
          const sorted = data.filter((user) => user.dead !== true);
          console.log(sorted);
          setData(sorted);
      filtered(sorted);
        } else {
          const sorted = [...soldiers].sort((a, b) => (b.hits / b.shots * 100) - (a.hits / a.shots * 100));
          setData(sorted);
        filtered(sorted);
        }
      } else {
        if(isChecked) {
          const sorted = data.filter((user) => user.dead !== true);
          console.log(sorted);
          setData(sorted);
          filtered(sorted);
        } else {
          const sorted = [...soldiers].sort((a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]);
          setData(sorted);
        filtered(sorted);
        }
        
      }
   
    };

    sortArray(sortType);
   
    
  }, [sortType, isChecked]);
```

It basically takes the value of selector and sorts the array based on the type of value that was selected, and if the "isDead" checkbox it checks it filters the array and removes the instances that have "dead" set as true.
However, my problem is that I'm repeating the code constantly and I want to add more checkboxes to filter the array by more options if they are checked, and if I want to do that, the way it is currently set up would mean that I would repeat the same code over and over with different values. How can I make the code less repeatable if I want to add even more checkbox options to filter arrays, for example using the "class" values? For example have multiple checkboxes to display "Field Medic", "Assault Infantry" etc.

Comment: Start by moving the identical `if (isChecked) { ... }` blocks out of the outer `if..else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key problem here is that with your approach you need to declare `sorted` inside the `if` branches, which is why you need all the duplicated `setData(sorted)` etc.

So the solution is to get `sorted` to become available in the scope outside of the conditions, but still apply the conditions.

There are different possible approaches to it.

*(My examples don't reflect your exact use case, but I guess they illustrate the Idea, and from there it will be easy.)*

E.g. extract the conditions into a separate function:

```
const getSorted = function( sortType, isChecked ){
  if(sortType === "accuracy") {
    // ...
    return data.filter((user) => user.dead !== true);
  } else {
    // ...
  }
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
  const sorted = getSorted( sortType, isChecked ); // <-- all the if-conditions are in here
  setData( sorted );
  filtered( sorted );
  // ...
}
```

Another approach would be to define an object that specifies some properties of the `sortType`, like conditions, modifiers, ... E.g.:

```
const sortTypesSpec = {
  'accuracy': {
    sortFunction: (a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty],
    filterFunction: (user) => user.dead !== true,
    // ... other properties ?
  },
  'default': {
    // ...
  }
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ...
  const sorted = isChecked
    ? data.filter( sortTypesSpec[ sortType ].filterFunction )
    : [...soldiers].sort( sortTypesSpec[ sortType ].sortFunction );

  setData( sorted );
  filtered( sorted );
  // ...
```

Of course, you can extract that into a function as well.